# Не могу добавить в БД числа от 1 до 112

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView idHeroText;
DataHelper dataHelper;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    idHeroText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.idHeroText);

    dataHelper = new DataHelper(this);

    getHeroe();


    Log.e("Log" , "BD = " + dataHelper.getHeroId());


}


private ArrayList<Hero> getHeroe() {

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 112; i++) {

         Log.e("Log" , "BD = " + i);

        Hero hero = new Hero();
        hero.setNum(i);
        list.add(hero);
    }
    return list;

}}
```

// Мой БД

```
public class DataHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DB_NAME = "dc.db";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TABLE_HERO = "heroes";
private static final String DC_ID = "dc_id";
private static final String DC_FAVORITE = "favorite";


public DataHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String sql = "create table " + TABLE_HERO + " (" +
            BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            DC_ID + " INTEGER," +
            DC_FAVORITE + " INTEGER);";
    db.execSQL(sql);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public void saveHero(ArrayList<Hero> list) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    for (Hero hero : list) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DC_ID, hero.getNum());
        database.insert(TABLE_HERO, null, values);
    }
    database.close();

}

public ArrayList<Hero> getHeroId() {

    ArrayList<Hero> list = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_HERO, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Hero hero = new Hero();
        hero.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID)));
        hero.setNum(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DC_ID)));
        list.add(hero);
    }
    cursor.close();
    database.close();
    return list;
}}
```

// Model

```
public class Hero {

private int num;
private int id;

public Hero() {

}

public int getNum() {


    Log.e("Log" , "Model = " + getNum());

    return num;
}

public void setNum(int num) {
    this.num = num;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}}
```

Comment: В логе показывает так :

08-04 16:38:36.090 6453-6453/com.mnd.testbd E/Log: BD = []

Comment: Не вижу в коде, чтобы где-то вызывался ваш метод сохранения данных в БД `saveHero(ArrayList<Hero> list)`.